# Implement a Back Button on Navigation Bar in iPhone App

Tags: iphone

Just recently took over a project from my developer. I'm a noob to coding, but can figure things out pretty well. I'm just trying to implement Back button on one of my screens. It already has the navigation Bar, but no back button, just the title.

Is there a guide on how to get this implemented? Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Update = Here is the code:

```
<object class="IBUINavigationController" id="144954994">
<reference key="NSNextResponder" ref="191373211"/>
<int key="NSvFlags">290</int>
<string key="NSFrameSize">{320, 44}</string>
<reference key="NSSuperview" ref="191373211"/>
<bool key="IBUIOpaque">NO</bool>
<bool key="IBUIClearsContextBeforeDrawing">NO</bool>
<int key="IBUIBarStyle">2</int>
<object class="NSArray" key="IBUIItems">
<bool key="EncodedWithXMLCoder">YES</bool>
<object class="IBUINavigationController" id="445217273">
<reference key="IBUINavigationController" ref="144954994"/>
<string key="IBUITitle">Answer Question</string>
</object>
</object>
</object>
```

Comment: I don't want to sound like a prick and mean no offense, I started where you are, but my recommendation is to sit down with a good overview of Objective-C and iPhone programming.  Download and study the sample apps until you really understand what is happening. After a while you start seeing the beauty of Obj-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using UINavigationController's?  If so, it's automatically put there when you push a view.

(Update based on comment) Using a UINavigationBar

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

```
 bar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = // set to a UIButton
```

Comment: No, I'm not. I have a UINavigationBar, added a Bar Button Item. I wasn't using UINavigationController. How do I do so?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a UINavigationController to control your stack of views, the Back button is automatically added for you when you push on a new view.

Comment: If your UINavigationController is an IBOutlet, you'll need to open the xib in Interface Builder and specify the Back Button title in the Navigation Item Attributes, otherwise the back button will not show up on your nav bar.